# ProFTPD server - SFTP only for 1 user

Tags: linux, ftp, centos6, proftpd

We have an FTP server setup using ProFTPD and CentOS, ProFTPD has been setup with FTP, FTPS, FTPES and SFTP access.

We have a user who only wants to allow access to their account via SFTP.

Is there away in ProFTPD to disable protocols on a per user basis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked it out and I using the

```
  <IfUser username>
    <Limit LOGIN>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>
  </IfUser>
```

stuff in the virtual host for each protocol.